# How do I get sound from speakers instead of TV over HDMI

Tags: sound, hdmi, speakers, tv

I'm a noob with this OS.
I installed Ubuntu today and it's up and working surprisingly fast ^^

My only issue is:
I got my PC connected to speakers and connected to my TV via HDMI, when I try to play sound it plays only through the TV-speakers and my other speakers don't play any sound. 
Anyone knows how I can make it play sound from my normal speakers instead of TV speakers?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you running? 12.04, 13.10, 14.04?

Comment: I am running 12.04

Answer (score 0):

Download and install PulseAudio - you'll find items in the output tab that will help. I found setting to HDMI vs. internal speakers helped on the last version of Ubuntu. Seems to have fixed it now. :)